# generating a log normal distribution using R

Tags: python, r

I would like to generate a log-normal distribution to use in my Python code to alter the rate in which I hit the server. Can anyone please guide me in generating the same?

Comment: You're looking to generate random values from a log normal distribution?  Do you know how to generate random values from a normal distribution?  Your question title suggests you're using R but your question itself suggests python.  Can you clarify whether you want to use python or R?

Comment: no i don't know how how to generate the values from a normal distribution.yes i want to use R to generate the random values and  use Rpy package to use those values in my python code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In R you can use `rlnorm` but why don't you use numpy and do it directly in Python.

Look at this document: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.lognormal.html

Comment: thank you very much.i will look at this and if i have any further queries i will get back to you.

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 5):

Unless your heart is set on using R there is no need for external libraries.  Python's builtin [random module](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html) is well suited for general purpose use.  It can generate random numbers from a variety of common distributions.

```
import math
import random

#generate 10k lognormal samples with mean=0 and stddev=1
samples = [random.lognormvariate(0,1) for r in xrange(10000)]

#demonstrate the mean and stddev are close to the target
#compute the mean of the samples
log_samples = [math.log(sample) for sample in samples]
mu = sum(log_samples)/len(samples)
#compute the variance and standard deviation
variance = sum([(val-mu)**2 for val in log_samples])/(len(log_samples)-1)
stddev = var**0.5

print('Mean: %.4f' % mu)
print('StdDev: %.4f' % stddev)

#Plot a histogram if matplotlib is installed
try:
    import pylab
    hist = pylab.hist(samples,bins=100)
    pylab.show()

except:
    print('pylab is not available')
```

If you are using Rpy2 this should get you started:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects

#reference the rlnorm R function
rlnorm = robjects.r.rlnorm

#generate the samples in R
samples = rlnorm(n=10000, meanlog=1, sdlog=1)
```

Comment: thank you.very much.can u please tell tell me how to do it in R

Comment: I added an Rpy2 example, refer to the Rpy2 [documentation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/Lognormal.html) and the R [documentation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/Lognormal.html)